# Eloquent Create statement not passing variable

Tags: php, eloquent, slim

So I'm getting this error when I try to do a simple create statement as below:

```
//echo $request->getParam('collectionName');

$collection = ItemCollection::create([

   'collection' => $request->getParam('collectionName'),
]);
```

And that gives me this

```
**1364 Field 'collection' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `collections` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2017-05-07 23:33:44, 2017-05-07 23:33:44))**
```

Which is moot because I'm passing in the collectionName.

My Input:

```
<input type="text" id="collectionName" name="collectionName" class="form-control">
```

If I echo $request->getParam('collectionName') it's exactly as expected.

I've declared the fillable

```
class ItemCollection extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [ 'collection' ];
```

My SQL

[image: My SQL]

I have actually renamed the field name/POST var because it was initially *name*  but just in case, I don't know, some conflict with *name* that has never come up before, I renamed it to collectionName.

Am I missing something here? I am passing the collectionName in so it shouldn't care about the default.  It's obviously getting to the SQL part, so that's not the problem.  The fillable and create code was copied directly from my other working code so not a typo (and I've redone it twice). But still, it has to be in the fillable part or the create part.  But where?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code. Is this a typo mistake?
`collection' => $request->getParam('collectionName'),`

Comment: The missing ' ? I checked but that was in my code, must have gotten dropped when messing with lines and spaces.  Also fixed title because I don't know where that one came from.